# Embedded resource txt file is not updating

Tags: c#

I have a project with a .txt file in a folder. The .txt file is set to Embedded Resource.

I use this code to read it:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var manifestResources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

string s = manifestResources.Single(c => c.EndsWith("Cats.txt"));
```

Which works great.

However I updated Cats.txt and noticed my project didn't update.

I deleted Cats.txt and found that it is still working fine and reading the file.

I tried cleaning my solution, rebuilding, and iisreset, but it seems to insist the file is still there in the assembly despite me removing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are reading an updated dll, instead of the old one ?

Comment: Did you delete `obj` and `bin` folders before rebuild?

Comment: Deleted bin and obj, rebuilt, same problem.

Comment: I had success deleting program.dll and program.Properties.Resources.resources.  I'm guessing that visual studio (roughly speaking) won't relink the resources file if it hasn't changed, and won't rebuild the resources file unless its been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed this by restarting visual studio. I have no idea how that affected it.

When I inspected the properties of 'assembly', the CodeBase attribute was pointing to an older copy of the DLL in a completely different folder, that was somewhere else on my hard disk, that I had open in another Visual Studio window.

I have no idea what underlying mechanism caused this to happen, I definitely had the correct version of the solution open and I was debugging it.

Closing the solution and opening it again fixed it. Chalk this one up to bizarro caching behaviour or something.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the problem is solved by Cleaning the solution first, and then Building it again.  I did not have to quit Visual Studio to update my embedded resource.

Answer (score 2):

Rebuild solution (or startup project) updates embedded resources.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, cleaning building and many other things didn't work. I had to modify the resource designer. After that, the resources were rebuil correctly

Answer (score 1):

Embedded files do not "automatically" refresh on build / debug.

If you want to ensure it will be done "automatically" you can in "Project Properties" insert in "Build" section, Events / Pre-built Events include:

```
echo "===== START - CUSTOM PRE-BUILD CLEANUP ======================="
del "$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)"*.* /F /Q
del "$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)"*.* /F /Q
echo "===== DONE - CUSTOM PRE-BUILD CLEANUP ======================="
```

[image: Project Properties - Prebuilt Event]

There are under circumstances issues with some files being removed. If that is the case you can use more granular selection.

```
echo "===== START - CUSTOM PRE-BUILD CLEANUP OF BIN ======================="
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)*.*") do if not "%%~xf"==".json" echo "Deleting %%f"
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)*.*") do if not "%%~xf"==".json" del "%%f" /F /Q
echo "===== DONE - CUSTOM PRE-BUILD CLEANUP OF BIN ======================="
echo "===== START - CUSTOM PRE-BUILD CLEANUP OF OBJ ======================="
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.*") do if not "%%~xf"==".json" echo "Deleting %%f"
for %%f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.*") do if not "%%~xf"==".json" del "%%f" /F /Q
echo "===== DONE - CUSTOM PRE-BUILD CLEANUP OF OBJ ======================="
```

Tested thoroughly in several projects / complex solutions. This answer applies to VS2022 as of 05/2023.

Comment: This should be the correct answer imo, the other answers that mention `clean` or `rebuild` were not sufficient in my case, it's true that some IntermediateFiles are kept after clean, in my case it was a cached DLL, which wasn't deleted (I assume because the source code hadn't changed). Either make a dummy change somewhere in the code everytime you update a resource, or chose this approach for reliable embedded resource updates